# I would LOVE to add a value to an array please

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add the value "peanuts" to the bag array in Java Script. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
var bag = [];
{
for (i=0; i<bag.length; i++) {
    bag.push([i] === "peanuts");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would LOVE to answer `bag.push('peanuts')`. How can an _index_ equal to a string. `bag` have no elements, so `for` will not be executed. No need of block around `for` so  `{}` can be removed

Comment: @Tushar not to mention the loop in an empty array.

Comment: Why the comparison `[i] === "peanuts"`?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Was adding that :)

Comment: @Tushar why did you add code that wasn't there before?

Comment: @CurlyCorvus It was there, OP might has added in short time so not showing in the revision history

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are looping over an empty array. This loop will never iterate since the array is being defined right over it without being filled before the loop.

Second, what you're *pushing* into the array is in fact the result of the condition `[i] === "peanuts"` which if it was a valid condition, will result in a boolean value.

As @Tushar said, you should use `bag.push("peanuts")` to add the string `"peanuts"` to the array `bag`. So let's say your code could be like this(unless you describe what kind of condition you want inside the `for` loop):

```
var bag = [];
bag.push("peanuts");
```

By the way, you're using an unnecessary *scope* block:

```
var bag = [];
{ // <-- Unnecessary scope block
    for (i=0; i < bag.length; i++) {
        bag.push([i] === "peanuts");
    }
} // <-- Unnecessary scope block
```

Some [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Examples) examples.

Answer (score 0):

This example adds peanuts to the bag array using the `push` command and then checks if the element is in the array using the `indexOf` function. This last function will return -1 if the element is not in the array, otherwise it returns the first index position the element was found at

```js
var bag = [];
bag.push("monkeys")
bag.push("peanuts")
bag.push("bananas")

if (bag.indexOf("peanuts") >= 0) {
  document.write("Found my peanuts at index " + bag.indexOf("peanuts"))
}
```